# Boost::asio: Getting the ip address of the remote that has connected to a server

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am currently writing a TCP server/client pair in C++ using the boost::asio library. When coding the TCPServer class, I decided to create a function that handles accepting the connections (analyzes the output of acceptor::accept and decides what to do) that will handle a while loop.

I would like to get the ip connection of the client that just connected to the server, and the closes thing I found is the remote_endpoint function of the socket. Is there any other valid option? Or do I have to analyze each message that has been received?

Answer (score 1):

> analyzes the output of acceptor::accept and decides what to do

Does this help:

```
asio::io_context io;
tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, 12345});
while (true) {
    tcp::socket s = acc.accept();

    std::cout << "Got connection from " << s.remote_endpoint() << "\n";
    decide_what_to_do(std::move(s));
}
```

I left error-handling out for this illustration, so exceptions terminate the program.

Comment: So the remote_endpoint is actually the connection that is being received, no?

Comment: It represents the origin of the connection being received, yes. The socket *represents* the connection.